# Rails 3 and routing

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have in my application 3 controllers - **persons**, **registrations**, **informations**. 
My URLs looks this (e.g.): **myweb.com/persons/add**, **myweb.com/persons/list**, **myweb.com/registrations/new**, **myweb.com/informations/old**, **myweb.com/informations/best** etc.

And I would like to ask you, if is possible to have URL in shape **myweb.com/luis**, **myweb.com/megan** or **myweb.com/paul** -- these names are from table persons and I would like to have these name so independently in URL...

So I would like to ask you about favor, how could this be done, how this situation to solve...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the solution if you explore the [Routing Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). You have to make custom routes for your elements like:

```
match ':person_name'
```

However, I see a problem in what you are asking for, because you could find duplicated names in your databases and the urls should be unique; so you need to filter them accordingly.